# Converting hexadecimal digit to two's complement

Tags: math, binary, hex

So I have the number 'E' which is 14 in decimal and 1110 in binary. To get the two's complement I first get the one's complement and add 1, so I get:

One's complement: 0001
Two's complement: 0010

So the answer in decimal form is 2, but the textbook says the answer is -2. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 0xe is -2 in twos complement notation. If you twos complement it, you get 2

Comment: @Kartman so since 1110 is -2 in two's complement notation, does that mean we would only use the one's complement and then add one when the number is negative?

Comment: @Blooper Perhaps the most important detail you need to realize is that the whole reason for two's complement is that a computer doesn't have to recognize the difference and can instead just use a simpler unsigned adder to perform signed addition. For your purposes as a human, yes -- you need to look at the sign bit. If it is a 1 then you perform the conversion and prefix a hand-written '-'. Otherwise, not. But to a computer? It just doesn't care. Try hand adding -2 to +3, or 1110 to 0011. The result is 0001, which is right. Hand add -2 to +1. The result is 1111, which is -1. Also right.

Answer (score 2):

To get the 2's complement you must define the number of bits.

The most significant bit is the sign bit.

So if the number of bits is 8 then you should get:

1. 14 is 00001110 (MSb=0 : positive)
2. -14 is 11110010 (MSb=1 : negative)

if the number of bits is 4:

1. you cannot code +14
2. +2 is 0010
3. -2 is 1110

2's complement of A is 2^n-A which we can get also if we apply: 1's complement + 1 (since the 1's complement is 2^n-1-A)

That is why 14 as raw binary is -2 as a 2's complement on 4 bits (it is 16-2 since 2^4=16) and there is a reason for that. In fact, the goal is to get a negative number coding where we can still have right results when applying basic operators like adding for instance on negative numbers, positive numbers and a mix of them.

Note: MSb is the most significant bit. Do not confuse with MSB (most significant byte).